# Monitor keeps waking up and going to sleep after lockscreen

Tags: suspend, power-management

I have a triple monitor setup if it makes any difference.

When i lock my desktop it goes to sleep/shuts down monitors after a short time as expected.

My issue is that they keep waking up after this, and immediately goes to sleep again in what i believe may be around 20min cycles. When they wake up they do not display the lock screen, my main monitor outputs only a blue color for a few seconds and then back to sleep.

Since i have my desktop in my bedroom this creates an annoying blue light to regularly blast out over the room during the nights.

I assume some program is causing this, is there any logs of what and when it wakes up and from what?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a faulty monitor? I had a similar issue with my old monitor, only it woke up at random intervals. It was just a hardware fault.

Comment: Im pretty sure since i dual boot with Windows and dont have the same issue there. I also tried to recreate this issue and the blue colored screen seems to be my monitors "No HDMI Signal"-screen.

Comment: I just installed, two good monitors. Having the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04. Had no issue on windows. When I got to a lock screen my monitors shut off and come back on. I suspect it has to do with the lock screen not blanking and the clock changing time. I'll note since you noted a blue light my monitor is the same waking with a bright blue light.. I have an ASUS monitor that is detected as Ancor Communications Inc 24" in display.

Comment: im facing similar issue. 3 monitor setup and at random interval it wakes the screens, im suspecting that it is the notifications

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was in dconf

```
/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/show-in-lock-screen : False
```

see for more https://vitux.com/turn-off-disable-notifications-on-your-ubuntus-lock-screen/

Comment: Same using gsettings: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-in-lock-screen false`